# If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = 1$, then what is the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, infinity

> If $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = 1$$
>   then
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)dx$$
>   is equal to which of $0$, $1$, $-1$, $2$?

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL9Pj.png))

I tried this first directly, then after putting specific functions also. In both cases, I am not getting. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: This is not a proper method per se but you can consider $f(x)=\frac {e^{-|x|}}{2}$

Comment: the value is $1$, from [Glasser's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem).